# django forms for filtering

Tags: django, forms, filter

I am trying to make a form for filtering a table by its columns , condition and text given by users.(text is not required)
for example, the user selects a column, greater,less, equals etc.

*forms*

```
class FilterForm(forms.Form):
    COLUMN_FILTER_CHOICES = (
        ('title', 'Title'),
        ('quantity', 'Quantity'),
        ('distance', 'Distance'),
    )

    CONDITION_FILTER_CHOICES = (
        ('equals', 'Equals'),
        ('contains', 'Contains'),
        ('greater', 'Greater'),
        ('lower', 'Lower'),
    )

    search = forms.CharField(required=False)
    column_filter_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COLUMN_FILTER_CHOICES)
    condition_filter_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CONDITION_FILTER_CHOICES)
```

*views*

```
class TableView(ListView):
    model = Table
    template_name = 'spa/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'table'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('search')
        column_filter_field = self.request.GET.get('column_filter_field')
        condition_filter_field = self.request.GET.get('condition_filter_field')

        return Table.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tables'] = Table.objects.all()

        context['form'] = FilterForm(initial={
            'search': self.request.GET.get('search', ''),
            'column_filter_field': self.request.GET.get('column_filter_field', ''),
            'condition_filter_field': self.request.GET.get('condition_filter_field', ''),
        })
        return context
```

*template*

```
<form action="" method="get" class="inline">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.column_filter_field }}
    {{ form.condition_filter_field }}
    {{ form.search }}

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Search">
</form>
```

the form is now working now, there is no response from the form.

and i need to refresh my table in real time without updating page, i cant find any information to filter in real time , is it possible to do with django?

Comment: Updating a page without refreshing a page is possible with JavaScript. There are many tutorials on the Internet that show you how to use JavaScript with Django.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use a javascript library such as [datatable](https://datatables.net/).
Your Django view will populate the table with all entries and you will have a user friendly interface to search, filter, arrange data as users like, on the client side, without calling the backend. It also supports Ajax processing if needed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).